# Object player - issue with validator

Tags: html, validation

my friend has added a player into her site which has been created long ago. Now I want to validate her site in html5. This was the very first code:

```html
 <div class="player">
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="975" height="30" class="player" align="middle">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="movie" value="player.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="best" />
        <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#999999" />
        <embed src="player.swf" quality="best" scale="noscale" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#999999" width="975" height="30" name="player2" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
```

Validator says that parametres classid and codebase are obsolete. when I remove them, it works. But validator also says that I must specify date and type parameters in object tag. The playing file is mp3. But when I specify the date parameter (url), a special design of the player disappears and appears standard ugly player. When I try to trick that and leave the date parameter empty, the validator screams that the parametre date cannot be empty. Google seems to not know this problem at all. Any ideas? Thank you.

Edited code:

```html
   <div class="player">
      <object width="975" height="30" class="player" align="middle" data="mp3/gymn/gymn.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="movie" value="player.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="best" />
        <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#999999" />
        <embed src="player.swf" quality="best" scale="noscale" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#999999" width="975" height="30" name="player2" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
      </object>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which doctype are you using?

Comment: I am using html5 (<!doctype html>). When I switch to html 4.01 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">, then I am not getting errors above, but the validator dislikes all the parametres of <embed> tag except src. When I remove them, the player works, but it's not styled. I can add them back by using CSS, but the transparent background is not working for some reason (probably because the player is flash/swf) so design of the player is broken. style="width: 975px; height: 30px; background-color: transparent;"

Comment: A live site would be helpful in order to help you. But I would advise you to replicate the player using native HTML5 audio if possible, flash requires plugin and is not supported in iOS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will do it if necessary. The site is not online yet, but exactly the same player is available on frontpage of the site on http://ruslana.ua/en/ (above the horisontal menu).

Comment: Update: I have learned that the tag <embed> won't validate in html4, just in html5. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the `align` attribute (because it's obsolete) from `object` and `embed` tag and use `id` instead of `name` (also because it's obsolete) in the `embed` tag like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Flash test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="player">
            <object width="975" height="30" class="player" data="mp3/gymn/gymn.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="movie" value="player.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="best" />
                <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#999999" />
                <embed src="player.swf" quality="best" scale="noscale" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#999999" width="975" height="30" id="player2" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
          </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now it's valid HTML5.